# How to programmatically remove a rendered v-for element from the DOM when using a click event?

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to use [V-Animate-CSS](https://github.com/jofftiquez/v-animate-css) to show a "deletion" animation when a delete button is pressed. **I am struggling with trying to specify the exact element to delete programmatically within a v-for loop.**

Let me explain:

I have the following vue `<template>` like so:

```
  <div
    v-for="x in divisionLangs"
    :key="x.P_uID"
  >

      <button
        type="button"
        @click.prevent="deleteCard(x.P_uID)"
      >
      </button>
    <transition name="bounce"
        <div v-if="show" class="card-body">
            <!-- card content is here -->
        </div>
    </transition>
```

My `<script>` section looks like so:

```
data() {
    return {
        show: true,
        divisionLangs: []
    }
}

deleteCard(id) {
  this.show = !this.show
  this.divisionLangs = this.divisionLangs.filter(x => x.P_uID !== id)
},
```

The data for the `divisionLangs` array looks like so:

```
[
  {
    P_uID: 789,
    ..blah...
  },
  {
    P_uID: 889,
    ...blah...
  }
]
```

**How can I structure this code so only the matching card item is deleted from the rendered list and not ALL of the card items? What happens right now is that all of the cards are deleted on the `deleteCard` method.**

Comment: I think you should define a component just for each item and implement deletion in that component

Comment: Example of how?

Comment: I have provided example as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a child component for each item like below:

Parent component:

```
<tmplate>
    <child-component v-for="x in divisionLangs" :key="x.P_uID" />
</template>
```

And in child component:

```
<button
        type="button"
        @click.prevent="deleteCard(x.P_uID)"
      >
      </button>
    <transition name="bounce"
        <div v-if="show" class="card-body">
            <!-- card content is here -->
        </div>
    </transition>
```

And Script part of child component:

```
data() {
    return {
        show: true,
        divisionLangs: []
    }
}

deleteCard(id) {
  this.show = !this.show
  this.divisionLangs = this.divisionLangs.filter(x => x.P_uID !== id)
},
```